# try/catch with JOptionPane, give error message for int

Tags: try-catch, user-input, joptionpane

How can I use try/catch so that the program only accepts string input for name and gives an error message if an int value is entered?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: a try/catch is not suitable for this. Also, keep in mind: "15" is a String value. You'll need to write validation based on your requirements